# Dart's .packages file and resolution of links

Tags: dart, webstorm, dart-polymer

Prior to upgrading to Dart 1.12.x version the following .html file links resolved correctly.

### .html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<link href='../../../../packages/core_elements/core_icon.html' rel='import'>
<link href='../../../../packages/html_components/utility/safe_html.html' rel='import'>

<polymer-element name='required-tooltip'>  
  <template>
      <div layout horizontal flex id='<tipp></tipp>'>
        <core-icon id='tip-icon' icon=''></core-icon>
        <h-safe-html id='label' content='<bol><u>Required</u><bold>'></h-safe-html>
      </div>
  </template>

  <script type='application/dart' src='required_tooltip.dart'></script>
</polymer-element>
```

Lines 2 and 3 imports did resolve correctly.

After upgrading to the new `.packages` file instead of the `/package` symlinks, none of the links are resolved.

What are the new rules to correct these issues?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean with "none of the links are resolved"? Are you talking about code navigation within WebStorm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WebStorm 11 EAP uses the `--no-package-symlinks` when you run `pub get` or `pub upgrade`. This feature is still experimental. A simple workaround is to run `pub get` or `pub upgrade` from command line and you get the `packages` directory with the symlinks back.

When resolution using the `.packages` file is supported everywhere, there shouldn't be any change necessary in your code even when the `packages` directory doesn't exist anymore.

See also https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/24237

Comment: Thanks Gunter. I am using WebStorm 11 EAP.